# PDFBox: How to “flatten” a PDF-form? Tried suggested answer but It's not working

Tags: java, pdfbox, xfa

I am Flatten the pdf using PDFBOX,but flatten the PDF is not working.What is missing in the code .

As per documentation I tried pdAcroForm.flatten(); but this is not producing flattened file

```
public class SampleConvert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

try
{
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(newFile("C:\\Users\\admin\\Extract\\Output\\Sample.pdf"));

PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm(); 
//pdAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(true); //With or without is also not working
pdAcroForm.flatten();

doc.save("C:\\Users\\admin\\Extract\\Output\\Sample_out.pdf");
doc.close();
System.out.println("Done");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

Expected result : is the Flattened file

Actual result coming : Same as original file (Which is wrong)

EDIT1: link for the pdf 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6bbjz1fyiaz5z7b/AAB2d4KspbLKDgsGLLjhwOgwa?dl=0

Input : Sample.pdf
Output :Sample_out.pdf  (Generated by code)

[Note : PDF is XFA form PDF so it might not be view able directly  .Need to convert to or open in adobe  ]

Comment: Pdfbox does not support XFA flattening. Or anything related to XFA except getting the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but URL https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDAcroForm.html   says it has Api to flattened the PDF form to normal PDF.

Comment: Yes but not XFA. Only acroform.

Comment: @Anil Please be aware that XFA uses PDF only as a transport envelope. Other than that XFA has nothing in common with PDF. Thus, if you are looking for a XFA specific functionality, it is not likely you find it in a generic PDF library unless that PDF library explicitly promises support for that XFA specific functionality,

Comment: @Tilman : I checked the PDF file(URL mentioned above) which is input for my program Is having Acroform tag in it .So my Understanding is that  should have got Flattened.

Comment: Yes your file has an AcroForm dictionary. But no acroForm fields. Open your file with `PDFBox PDFDebugger`, in the menu choose "View", "Show internal structure", then go to `Root/AcroForm/Fields` and there's your empty field array. Your XFA array is at `Root/AcroForm/XFA`.